# Arduino ESP32F-TFT-1.44 Driver

Tags: arduino-ide, lcd, esp32, tft

**Datasheet**  https://github.com/espressif/esp-hosted/files/5190376/ESP-32F.pdf

The below code is not working.
I can see only White screen

```
#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>    // Core graphics library
#include <Adafruit_ST7735.h> // Hardware-specific library for ST7735
#include <Adafruit_ST7789.h> // Hardware-specific library for ST7789
#include <SPI.h>

#define TFT_CS        26 // Hallowing display control pins: chip select
#define TFT_RST       16 // Display reset
#define TFT_DC        17 // Display data/command select
#define TFT_BACKLIGHT  13 // Display backlight pin


// OPTION 1 (recommended) is to use the HARDWARE SPI pins, which are unique
// to each board and not reassignable. For Arduino Uno: MOSI = pin 11 and
// SCLK = pin 13. This is the fastest mode of operation and is required if
// using the breakout board's microSD card.

// For 1.44" and 1.8" TFT with ST7735 (including HalloWing) use:
//Adafruit_ST7735 tft = Adafruit_ST7735(TFT_CS, TFT_DC, TFT_RST);

// For 1.54" TFT with ST7789:
//Adafruit_ST7789 tft = Adafruit_ST7789(TFT_CS, TFT_DC, TFT_RST);

// OPTION 2 lets you interface the display using ANY TWO or THREE PINS,
// tradeoff being that performance is not as fast as hardware SPI above.
#define TFT_MOSI 19  // Data out
#define TFT_SCLK 18  // Clock out
Adafruit_ST7735 tft = Adafruit_ST7735(TFT_CS, TFT_DC, TFT_MOSI, TFT_SCLK, TFT_RST);

float p = 3.1415926;

void setup(void) {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.print(F("Hello! ST77xx TFT Test"));

  //#ifdef ADAFRUIT_HALLOWING
  // HalloWing is a special case. It uses a ST7735R display just like the
  // breakout board, but the orientation and backlight control are different.
  tft.initR(INITR_HALLOWING);        // Initialize HalloWing-oriented screen
  pinMode(TFT_BACKLIGHT, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(TFT_BACKLIGHT, HIGH); // Backlight on
  //#else
  // Use this initializer if using a 1.8" TFT screen:
  //  tft.initR(INITR_BLACKTAB);      // Init ST7735S chip, black tab

  // OR use this initializer (uncomment) if using a 1.44" TFT:
  //  tft.initR(INITR_144GREENTAB); // Init ST7735R chip, green tab

  // OR use this initializer (uncomment) if using a 0.96" 180x60 TFT:
  //  tft.initR(INITR_MINI160x80);  // Init ST7735S mini display

  // OR use this initializer (uncomment) if using a 1.54" 240x240 TFT:
  //tft.init(240, 240);           // Init ST7789 240x240
  //#endif

  Serial.println(F("Initialized"));

  uint16_t time = millis();
  tft.fillScreen(ST77XX_BLACK);
  time = millis() - time;

  Serial.println(time, DEC);
  delay(500);

  // large block of text
  tft.fillScreen(ST77XX_BLACK);
  testdrawtext("Hello World asdf sdf adfsdf sdf sdf sdf sdf sdf ", ST77XX_BLACK);
  delay(1000);

  Serial.println("done");
  delay(1000);
}

void loop() {
  tft.invertDisplay(true);
  delay(500);
  tft.invertDisplay(false);
  delay(500);
}

void testdrawtext(char *text, uint16_t color) {
  tft.setCursor(0, 0);
  tft.setTextColor(color);
  tft.setTextWrap(true);
  tft.print(text);
}
```

Comment: are we supposed to guess what you expect the code to do, and what happens when you run the code, and what question you want to ask?

Comment: I can see only black screen.

Comment: then, what is the point of the lengthy program? ... reduce the code to minimum required to display a simple text message, such as "test" ... there should be an example sketch included with the library, try that first

Comment: from experience, I had the same problem with various displays with the example code above. using software SPI solved the problem many times. try it out. it's applicable in the code above with just some commenting.

Comment: What actual display do you have? Is it a ST7735 based one?

Comment: I checked my datasheet, but, there is no information, only TFT-1.44

Comment: According to the circuit diagram you provided, the `TFT_MOSI` is connected to pin 23, not pin 19. Pin 19 is for `MISO`, not `MOSI`.

Comment: @hcheung : thanks, that will be answer

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <WiFi.h>

#include <time.h>
#include "AudioFileSourcePROGMEM.h"
#include "AudioGeneratorTalkie.h"
#include "AudioOutputI2S.h"

#ifndef STASSID
#define STASSID "WIFI_SSID" 
#define STAPSK  "WIFI_PASSWORD"
#endif

const char *ssid = STASSID;
const char *pass = STAPSK;

long timezone = 7;
byte daysavetime = 1;



#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>    // Core graphics library
#include <Adafruit_ST7735.h> // Hardware-specific library for ST7735
#include <Adafruit_ST7789.h> // Hardware-specific library for ST7789
#include <SPI.h>

#define TFT_CS        26 // Hallowing display control pins: chip select
#define TFT_RST       16 // Display reset
#define TFT_DC        17 // Display data/command select
#define TFT_BACKLIGHT  13 // Display backlight pin


// OPTION 1 (recommended) is to use the HARDWARE SPI pins, which are unique
// to each board and not reassignable. For Arduino Uno: MOSI = pin 11 and
// SCLK = pin 13. This is the fastest mode of operation and is required if
// using the breakout board's microSD card.

// For 1.44" and 1.8" TFT with ST7735 (including HalloWing) use:
//Adafruit_ST7735 tft = Adafruit_ST7735(TFT_CS, TFT_DC, TFT_RST);

// For 1.54" TFT with ST7789:
//Adafruit_ST7789 tft = Adafruit_ST7789(TFT_CS, TFT_DC, TFT_RST);

// OPTION 2 lets you interface the display using ANY TWO or THREE PINS,
// tradeoff being that performance is not as fast as hardware SPI above.
#define TFT_MOSI 23  // Data out
#define TFT_SCLK 18  // Clock out
Adafruit_ST7735 tft = Adafruit_ST7735(TFT_CS, TFT_DC, TFT_MOSI, TFT_SCLK, TFT_RST);

float p = 3.1415926;

AudioGeneratorTalkie *talkie;
AudioOutputI2S *out;

bool GetLocalTime(struct tm * info, uint32_t ms) {
  uint32_t count = ms / 10;
  time_t now;

  time(&now);
  localtime_r(&now, info);

  if (info->tm_year > (2016 - 1900)) {
    return true;
  }

  while (count--) {
    delay(10);
    time(&now);
    localtime_r(&now, info);
    if (info->tm_year > (2016 - 1900)) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

int threshold = 40;
bool touch1detected = false;
bool touch2detected = false;

void gotTouch1() {
  touch1detected = true;
}

void gotTouch2() {
  touch2detected = true;
}
void initLCD() {
  tft.initR(INITR_HALLOWING);        // Initialize HalloWing-oriented screen
  pinMode(TFT_BACKLIGHT, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(TFT_BACKLIGHT, HIGH); // Backlight on


  Serial.println(F("Initialized"));

  uint16_t time = millis();
  tft.fillScreen(ST77XX_BLACK);
  time = millis() - time;

  Serial.println(time, DEC);
  delay(500);

  // large block of text
  tft.fillScreen(ST77XX_BLACK);

}
void setup(void) {

  touchAttachInterrupt(T2, gotTouch1, threshold);
  touchAttachInterrupt(T0, gotTouch2, threshold);

  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.print(F("Hello! ST77xx TFT Test"));

  initLCD();

  /*
    delay(1000);

    // tft print function!
    tftPrintTest();
    delay(4000);

    // a single pixel
    tft.drawPixel(tft.width() / 2, tft.height() / 2, ST77XX_GREEN);
    delay(500);

    // line draw test
    testlines(ST77XX_YELLOW);
    delay(500);

    // optimized lines
    testfastlines(ST77XX_RED, ST77XX_BLUE);
    delay(500);

    testdrawrects(ST77XX_GREEN);
    delay(500);

    testfillrects(ST77XX_YELLOW, ST77XX_MAGENTA);
    delay(500);

    tft.fillScreen(ST77XX_BLACK);
    testfillcircles(10, ST77XX_BLUE);
    testdrawcircles(10, ST77XX_WHITE);
    delay(500);

    testroundrects();
    delay(500);

    testtriangles();
    delay(500);

    mediabuttons();
    delay(500);

    Serial.println("done");
    delay(1000);


    //*/

  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  testdrawtext("Connecting to ", ST77XX_WHITE);

  WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }

  Serial.println("WiFi connected");

  tft.fillScreen(ST77XX_BLACK);
  testdrawtext(strcat("WiFi connected ", ""), ST77XX_WHITE);
  clearText();
  delay(1000);

  Serial.println("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  Serial.println("Contacting Time Server");

  configTime(3600 * timezone, daysavetime * 3600, "time.nist.gov", "0.pool.ntp.org", "1.pool.ntp.org");
  struct tm tmstruct ;
  do {
    tmstruct.tm_year = 0;
    Serial.printf(".");
    GetLocalTime(&tmstruct, 5000);
    delay(100);
  } while (tmstruct.tm_year < 100);

  audioLogger = &Serial;
  out = new AudioOutputI2S(0, 1);
  talkie = new AudioGeneratorTalkie();
  talkie->begin(nullptr, out);
}

char temp[300];

int alarmHours = 5;
int alarmMinutes = 44;

void loop() {
  //  tft.invertDisplay(true);
  //  delay(500);
  //  tft.invertDisplay(false);
  //  delay(500);

  struct tm tmstruct ;
  tmstruct.tm_year = 0;
  GetLocalTime(&tmstruct, 5000);
//  Serial.printf("\nNow is : %d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d Alarm %2d : %2d\n",
//                tmstruct.tm_year + 1900, tmstruct.tm_mon + 1,
//                tmstruct.tm_mday, tmstruct.tm_hour,
//                tmstruct.tm_min, tmstruct.tm_sec,
//                alarmHours, alarmMinutes);
  Serial.printf("\nNow is : %02d:%02d:%02d\n",
                tmstruct.tm_hour,
                tmstruct.tm_min, tmstruct.tm_sec);


  //  sprintf(temp, "%d-%02d-%02d% 02d:%02d:%02d Alarm %2d : %2d\n", tmstruct.tm_year + 1900, tmstruct.tm_mon + 1, tmstruct.tm_mday, tmstruct.tm_hour, tmstruct.tm_min, tmstruct.tm_sec, alarmHours, alarmMinutes);
  sprintf(temp, "%02d:%02d:%02d", tmstruct.tm_hour, tmstruct.tm_min, tmstruct.tm_sec);

  if (60 * alarmHours + alarmMinutes <= 60 * tmstruct.tm_hour + tmstruct.tm_min) {
    Serial.printf("-Alarm-");
    Serial.printf("\n** Now is : %d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d Alarm %2d : %2d\n",
                  tmstruct.tm_year + 1900, tmstruct.tm_mon + 1,
                  tmstruct.tm_mday, tmstruct.tm_hour,
                  tmstruct.tm_min, tmstruct.tm_sec,
                  alarmHours, alarmMinutes);
    //    sayTime(tmstruct.tm_hour, tmstruct.tm_min, talkie);
    //    initLCD();
  }

  //  clearText();

  tft.fillRect(40, 30, 50, 10, ST77XX_BLACK );
  //  testdrawtext(temp, ST77XX_WHITE);
  tft.setCursor(40, 30);
  tft.setTextColor(ST77XX_WHITE);
  //  tft.setTextWrap(true);
  tft.print(temp);


  delay(1000);

  if (touch1detected) {
    touch1detected = false;
    Serial.println("Touch 1 detected");
    alarmMinutes = alarmMinutes + 10;
  }
  if (touch2detected) {
    touch2detected = false;
    Serial.println("Touch 2 detected");
    alarmMinutes = alarmMinutes + 10;
  }
}

void testlines(uint16_t color) {
  tft.fillScreen(ST77XX_BLACK);
  for (int16_t x = 0; x < tft.width(); x += 6) {
    tft.drawLine(0, 0, x, tft.height() - 1, color);
    delay(0);
  }
  for (int16_t y = 0; y < tft.height(); y += 6) {
    tft.drawLine(0, 0, tft.width() - 1, y, color);
    delay(0);
  }

  tft.fillScreen(ST77XX_BLACK);
  for (int16_t x = 0; x < tft.width(); x += 6) {
    tft.drawLine(tft.width() - 1, 0, x, tft.height() - 1, color);
    delay(0);
  }
  for (int16_t y = 0; y < tft.height(); y += 6) {
    tft.drawLine(tft.width() - 1, 0, 0, y, color);
    delay(0);
  }

  tft.fillScreen(ST77XX_BLACK);
  for (int16_t x = 0; x < tft.width(); x += 6) {
    tft.drawLine(0, tft.height() - 1, x, 0, color);
    delay(0);
  }
  for (int16_t y = 0; y < tft.height(); y += 6) {
    tft.drawLine(0, tft.height() - 1, tft.width() - 1, y, color);
    delay(0);
  }

  tft.fillScreen(ST77XX_BLACK);
  for (int16_t x = 0; x < tft.width(); x += 6) {
    tft.drawLine(tft.width() - 1, tft.height() - 1, x, 0, color);
    delay(0);
  }
  for (int16_t y = 0; y < tft.height(); y += 6) {
    tft.drawLine(tft.width() - 1, tft.height() - 1, 0, y, color);
    delay(0);
  }
}

char prevText[300];

void clearText() {
  testdrawtext(prevText, ST77XX_BLACK);
}

void testdrawtext(char *text, uint16_t color) {
  strcpy(prevText, text);
  tft.setCursor(0, 0);
  tft.setTextColor(color);
  tft.setTextWrap(true);
  tft.print(text);
}

void testfastlines(uint16_t color1, uint16_t color2) {
  tft.fillScreen(ST77XX_BLACK);
  for (int16_t y = 0; y < tft.height(); y += 5) {
    tft.drawFastHLine(0, y, tft.width(), color1);
  }
  for (int16_t x = 0; x < tft.width(); x += 5) {
    tft.drawFastVLine(x, 0, tft.height(), color2);
  }
}

void testdrawrects(uint16_t color) {
  tft.fillScreen(ST77XX_BLACK);
  for (int16_t x = 0; x < tft.width(); x += 6) {
    tft.drawRect(tft.width() / 2 - x / 2, tft.height() / 2 - x / 2 , x, x, color);
  }
}

void testfillrects(uint16_t color1, uint16_t color2) {
  tft.fillScreen(ST77XX_BLACK);
  for (int16_t x = tft.width() - 1; x > 6; x -= 6) {
    tft.fillRect(tft.width() / 2 - x / 2, tft.height() / 2 - x / 2 , x, x, color1);
    tft.drawRect(tft.width() / 2 - x / 2, tft.height() / 2 - x / 2 , x, x, color2);
  }
}

void testfillcircles(uint8_t radius, uint16_t color) {
  for (int16_t x = radius; x < tft.width(); x += radius * 2) {
    for (int16_t y = radius; y < tft.height(); y += radius * 2) {
      tft.fillCircle(x, y, radius, color);
    }
  }
}

void testdrawcircles(uint8_t radius, uint16_t color) {
  for (int16_t x = 0; x < tft.width() + radius; x += radius * 2) {
    for (int16_t y = 0; y < tft.height() + radius; y += radius * 2) {
      tft.drawCircle(x, y, radius, color);
    }
  }
}

void testtriangles() {
  tft.fillScreen(ST77XX_BLACK);
  int color = 0xF800;
  int t;
  int w = tft.width() / 2;
  int x = tft.height() - 1;
  int y = 0;
  int z = tft.width();
  for (t = 0 ; t <= 15; t++) {
    tft.drawTriangle(w, y, y, x, z, x, color);
    x -= 4;
    y += 4;
    z -= 4;
    color += 100;
  }
}

void testroundrects() {
  tft.fillScreen(ST77XX_BLACK);
  int color = 100;
  int i;
  int t;
  for (t = 0 ; t <= 4; t += 1) {
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int w = tft.width() - 2;
    int h = tft.height() - 2;
    for (i = 0 ; i <= 16; i += 1) {
      tft.drawRoundRect(x, y, w, h, 5, color);
      x += 2;
      y += 3;
      w -= 4;
      h -= 6;
      color += 1100;
    }
    color += 100;
  }
}

void tftPrintTest() {
  tft.setTextWrap(false);
  tft.fillScreen(ST77XX_BLACK);
  tft.setCursor(0, 30);
  tft.setTextColor(ST77XX_RED);
  tft.setTextSize(1);
  tft.println("Hello World!");
  tft.setTextColor(ST77XX_YELLOW);
  tft.setTextSize(2);
  tft.println("Hello World!");
  tft.setTextColor(ST77XX_GREEN);
  tft.setTextSize(3);
  tft.println("Hello World!");
  tft.setTextColor(ST77XX_BLUE);
  tft.setTextSize(4);
  tft.print(1234.567);
  delay(1500);
  tft.setCursor(0, 0);
  tft.fillScreen(ST77XX_BLACK);
  tft.setTextColor(ST77XX_WHITE);
  tft.setTextSize(0);
  tft.println("Hello World!");
  tft.setTextSize(1);
  tft.setTextColor(ST77XX_GREEN);
  tft.print(p, 6);
  tft.println(" Want pi ? ");
  tft.println(" ");
  tft.print(8675309, HEX); // print 8,675,309 out in HEX!
  tft.println(" Print HEX!");
  tft.println(" ");
  tft.setTextColor(ST77XX_WHITE);
  tft.println("Sketch has been");
  tft.println("running for : ");
  tft.setTextColor(ST77XX_MAGENTA);
  tft.print(millis() / 1000);
  tft.setTextColor(ST77XX_WHITE);
  tft.print(" seconds.");
}

void mediabuttons() {
  // play
  tft.fillScreen(ST77XX_BLACK);
  tft.fillRoundRect(25, 10, 78, 60, 8, ST77XX_WHITE);
  tft.fillTriangle(42, 20, 42, 60, 90, 40, ST77XX_RED);
  delay(500);
  // pause
  tft.fillRoundRect(25, 90, 78, 60, 8, ST77XX_WHITE);
  tft.fillRoundRect(39, 98, 20, 45, 5, ST77XX_GREEN);
  tft.fillRoundRect(69, 98, 20, 45, 5, ST77XX_GREEN);
  delay(500);
  // play color
  tft.fillTriangle(42, 20, 42, 60, 90, 40, ST77XX_BLUE);
  delay(50);
  // pause color
  tft.fillRoundRect(39, 98, 20, 45, 5, ST77XX_RED);
  tft.fillRoundRect(69, 98, 20, 45, 5, ST77XX_RED);
  // play color
  tft.fillTriangle(42, 20, 42, 60, 90, 40, ST77XX_GREEN);
}
```

Comment: Please add an explanation for why this is an answer to the question. What does this code do and how does it solve the problem? What's with the audio stuff?